# sequelize query no result

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i am trying to make a costum query in `node js` using `sequelize`.

So i have my api call:

```
router.route('/api/divisionData/:division_id')
.get(function (req, res) {
    var division = Division.build();

    division.retrieveDataById(req.params.division_id, function (users) {
        if (users) {
            res.json(users);
        } else {
            res.status(401).send("Data not found");
        }
    }, function (error) {
        res.send("Data not found");
    });
});
```

And then i have my retrieveDataById:

```
sequelize.query("select division_id, (modules.user_id) as modules_taken, ROUND(avg(scores.score),2) as average_score from " +
                "user join " +
                "(select user_id, score from test_score " +
                "UNION ALL " +
                "select user_id, score from task_score WHERE status_id = 1 " +
                ") as scores " +
                "  on user.id = scores.user_id " +
                    "  join ( " +
                    "      SELECT user_id FROM test_score " +
                    "  UNION all " +
                    "  SELECT user_id FROM task_score WHERE status_id NOT IN (3) " +
                    "  UNION all " +
                    "  SELECT user_id FROM elearning_score " +
                    "  union all" +
                    "  SELECT user_id FROM academy_screening " +
                    "  union all" +
                    "  SELECT user_id FROM academy_evaluation " +
                    "  union all " +
                    "  select user_id FROM academy_survey " +
                    "  union al " +
                    "  select user_id FROM offline_score " +
"  ) as modules on user.id = modules.user_id WHERE division_id = " + user_id +"  group by division_id", {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(onSuccess).error(onError)
```

i have tested the query in MySql and it works fine however the return of this call is:

```
data not found
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure could be typo `select user_id FROM academy_survey " +                  "  union al " +` instead of `UNION all` but then shouldn't you catch the error object

Comment: Which version are you on? Have you tried using QueryTypes.RAW and using `.spread`

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier That gave me the same result (which means no data found)

Comment: Which sequelize version are you using?